# Use alarmManager and service to get data from server repeatedly

Tags: android, android-service, alarmmanager, android-notifications, android-alarms

My question is I want to verify every two hour that there is new data in the database, for that I create this user interface :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/speedAlert"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:hint="km/h"
            android:inputType="number" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/checkBoxSpeed"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnConfirmSpeed"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Confirm" />
```

so when user enter the value of the edittext and check the checkbox and confirm by clicking the button, an alarm is created and every two hour this alarm start a service :

```
btnConfirmSpeed.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            triggerAtTime = cal.getTimeInMillis()+ (1 * 30 * 60 * 1000); // starts in 30 minutes
            repeat_alarm_every = (2 * 60 * 60 * 1000); // repeat every 2 hour
            int _id = (int) System.currentTimeMillis();
            Intent intent = new Intent(Alarm.this, NotificaSpeed.class);
            //get the value of checkbox from sharedpreferences
                    boolean tgpref = pref.getBoolean("checkVitessePref", false); 
            String sp = speedAlert.getText().toString();
            if(checkBoxSpeed.isChecked()){
                if(sp.matches(""))
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "specify speed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                else 
                {
                    editor = pref.edit();
                    editor.putBoolean("checkVitessePref", true); // value to store
                    editor.putInt("speedalarm", Integer.parseInt(speedAlert.getText().toString()));
                    editor.commit();

                    pintent = PendingIntent.getService(Alarm.this, _id, intent, 0);
                    alarm = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
                    alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, triggerAtTime, repeat_alarm_every, pintent);


                } 
            }else {

                alarm.cancel(pintent);
                editor.putBoolean("checkVitessePref", false); // value to store
                editor.commit();
                stopService(new Intent(Alarm.this,NotificaSpeed.class));
            }

        }
    });
```

the NotificaSpeed is the service :

```
public class NotificaSpeed extends Service{

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}
@Override
public void onCreate() {

    mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(ns);
    super.onCreate();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    new VerifySpeedCar().execute();
    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}

public void notification(int carsNumber, int speed){
    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(NotificaSpeed.this);
    if(carsNumber != 0)

        notificationBuilder.setContentTitle(carsNumber+" cars are exceeding the speed");

                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                        .setAutoCancel(true);
    final int _idI = (int) System.currentTimeMillis();
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(NotificaSpeed.this, ListCars.class);
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, _idI, notificationIntent, 0);
    notificationBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);

    notificationBuilder.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND | Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS | Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE);

    mNotificationManager.notify(SIMPLE_NOTIFICATION_ID, notificationBuilder.build());

}

class VerifySpeedCar extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
    // Building Parameters
    List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(TAG_ACCOUNTID, accountID));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(TAG_SPEEDKPH, ""+speedpref)); // how can I get the value of edittext of the speed from the sharedpreferences?

        JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url, "GET", params);
        try {
            int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
            if (success == 1) {
                cars = json.getJSONArray(TAG_CARS);
                carsNumber = cars.length();
            } else 
                carsNumber = 0;

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    return null;
}
protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
  if( carsNumber != 0){
      notification(carsNumber, speedpref);
  }
}}}
```

first is that good way to do the verification or I am doing it wrong?
second how can I get the value of the edittext from the sharedpreferences?
finally when I close the app the service is stoped too, so when I start the app again the service is no more running but the value of checkbox is still checked, How can I resolve this?

thank you for taking the time to read my question. any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

**How to get the value of edittext from SharedPreference?**

Create SharedPreference and SharedPreference.Editor objects.

```
 SharedPreferences sp ;
 sp = this.getSharedPreferences("YOUR PREF NAME", 0);
```

I believe you are getting the value from edittext in String str like

```
str = ed.getText().toString();
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();
editor.putString("edit_text", str);
editor.commit();
```

**Retrieving the edittext value from SharedPreference**

If you're retrieving in the same activity then

```
String value = sp.getString("edit_text", null);
```

If in different activity then first instantiate the SharedPreference like this

```
SharedPreference sp = this.getSharedPreferences("YOUR PREF NAME", 0);
```

Comment: thank you @Aniruddha for your answer but this not working on service I tried it!

Comment: What is happening at that time? Can you post that code?

Comment: I used this SharedPreferences prefs  = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE); I think I have to create my sharedpreferences, my question now is the problem of the service is it obligatory to use service or just ana alarmManager? because when the service is stoped the checkbox still checked so have can I verify that my service is still ranning?