# Use AlarmManger to start service

Tags: android, android-service, alarmmanager

I use alarmManager to launch service every hour that service create notification, but the result is that I get more than one notification in one hour,is the service launch the onStartCommand() method or what happen exactly?

AlarmManager :

```
cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        triggerAtTime = cal.getTimeInMillis()+ (1 * 30 * 60 * 1000); // starts in 30 minutes
        repeat_alarm_every = (1 * 60 * 60 * 1000); // repeat every 2 hour
        int _id = (int) System.currentTimeMillis();
        Intent intent = new Intent(Alarm.this, NotificaSpeed.class);
        pintent = PendingIntent.getService(Alarm.this, _id, intent, 0);
        alarm = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, triggerAtTime, repeat_alarm_every, pintent);
```

service :

```
    public class NotificaSpeed extends Service{

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}
@Override
public void onCreate() {

    mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(ns);
    super.onCreate();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    new VerifySpeedCar().execute();
    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}

public void notification(int carsNumber, int speed){
    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(NotificaSpeed.this);
    if(carsNumber != 0)

        notificationBuilder.setContentTitle(carsNumber+" cars are exceeding the speed");

                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                        .setAutoCancel(true);
    final int _idI = (int) System.currentTimeMillis();
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(NotificaSpeed.this, ListCars.class);
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, _idI, notificationIntent, 0);
    notificationBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);

    notificationBuilder.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND | Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS | Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE);

    mNotificationManager.notify(SIMPLE_NOTIFICATION_ID, notificationBuilder.build());

}

class VerifySpeedCar extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
    // Building Parameters
    List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(TAG_ACCOUNTID, accountID));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(TAG_SPEEDKPH, ""+speedpref)); // how can I get the value of edittext of the speed from the sharedpreferences?

        JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url, "GET", params);
        try {
            int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
            if (success == 1) {
                cars = json.getJSONArray(TAG_CARS);
                carsNumber = cars.length();
            } else 
                carsNumber = 0;

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    return null;
}
protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
  if( carsNumber != 0){
      notification(carsNumber, speedpref);
  }
}}}
```

Comment: @SMR I already did but no ansewrs http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23539400/use-alarmmanager-and-service-to-get-data-from-server-repeatedly

Comment: just post your code only related to Alarm Manager and service here.

Comment: @SMR my question is simple: when alarm start service, the code on onStartCommand() excuted once or more that one time because my service verify in the database if there is any new data, so I won't that the service do that every single second

Answer (score 1):

because the `Service` being repeated by `AlramManager` it is important to stop the `Service` when the task is completed.

**MyService.java**

```
public class MyService extends Service {
    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
        //do your task here

        stopSelf(); // important to stop service here
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

you already know how to start service using alarm manager.

Comment: thank you for your answer,so is this the best way to get data periodically? and is this the right way to start service? last question please, when I verify in the database I don't want to verify in the data that I already verified any idea please.

Comment: `when I verify in the database I don't want to verify in the data that I already verified any idea please` I dont get your point @AbdelkarimTinguer